# How much do nap facilities improve worker productivity?

Tags: productivity, work-life-balance, flextime

I was reading [this](https://academic.oup.com/qje/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/qje/qjab013/6217436?redirectedFrom=fulltext) economics paper on sleep efficiency, and came across:

> short afternoon naps at the workplace improved an overall index of outcomes by 0.12 standard deviations

Are there any other studies/statistics that experiment and measure (or otherwise estimate) any possible productivity gains (or, more fundamentally, the effects on cognition, decision-making, or worker well-being) from allowing sleeping in some form/s?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Google orders things according to SEO. Much academic research is *not* contained in the non-deep web (i.e. lots is behind Elsevier and other paywalls, and therefore won't appear in Google). Google does little to distinguish fact from completely made up content optimised for web (ask someone who has googled their medical symptoms). I'm not after some flimsy Google results here, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not an academic, but from personal experience we had a chap in my forestry days who used to disappear into the bush after lunch and go to sleep if no one noticed him. We found that his productivity actually improved a bit if he was woken up.

Comment: @Kilisi "**if** he was woken up". I laughed pretty hard at that bit.

Comment: IMO (utterly non scientific), they are like other fluffy office perks, in that they improve productivity by improving the degree to which staff feel valued, and thus the degree to which staff care about the work. If the staff stop caring about the work, the number of extra hours-worked or lines-of-code-written to make up for it would be enormous.

Answer (score 3):

I worked at a company who had a "meditation room" which was basically a small, neutral office/meeting room with a long flat sofa and a vacant/in-use sign on the door - I used it maybe once per week for a 10-20 minute power nap, as I know other people did.

However, some staff regarded this room as a bit of a joke, and there were the inevitable rumours about who had slept with who in it. Apparently a few staff regularly used it to stay over if they went out partying after work and didn't fancy the train home.

So overall I would have said it was a net positive for me and increased my productivity (as a last resort when the coffee wasn't working), but that is of course subjective.

Comment: From personal experience I find that in general sleep trumps caffeine for increasing productivity.